# Confirmation about Use Case diagram

Tags: uml, use-case

In a restaurant management system waiter can do the following tasks:

```
Create Order
Add new item to order
Remove an item from order
Delete order
Close order.
```

How to draw a use case diagram with these tasks ?

Please help me. I have drawn a use case diagram but cannot upload the image because I do not have enough reputation.

Comment: First, in order to describe a "Use Case" U.M.L. diagram, you need to specify who is doing those activities or actions [a.k.a. one or more "actor" (s) ], in this example "Waiter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple. See picture of use case definitions on the picture belowe. Diagram is created in context of Restaurant Management System.
Please notice that, Add new Item and Remove item from order are not a UseCases. This operations must be included in scenario of Create Order and Update Order as a steps of usecase realization.

I hope it will help you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can I link "Add Item" and "Remove Item" to "Create Order" task as <<include>> or <<extend>> instead of "Update Order"?

Comment: Yes it is possible to add Add Item and Remove Item usecases and connect them using include or extend. But as I mentioned, "add item" and "remove item" are rather steps of use case realization then usecases. And it is quite unclear what type of relationship include or extend to use.